# same for loop worked if opened file using open() & reader(), but didn't work for pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I opened a file in jupyter notebook using open() and read(). I used a for loop to find duplicates. It worked perfectly.

I opened the same file using pandas data frame. The for loop that I used before did not work. It did not produce any results.

that for loop in pandas does not print anything.

```py
duplicate_apps = []
unique_apps = []

for app in android:
    name = app[0]
    if name in unique_apps:
        duplicate_apps.append(name)
    else:
        unique_apps.append(name)

print('Number of duplicate apps:', len(duplicate_apps))
print('\n')
print('Examples of duplicate apps:', duplicate_apps[:15])
```

This loop worked perfectly when I used open() and reader(), but did not work when I opened the file using pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you iterate over a dataframe like in:

```
for app in android:
    name = app[0]
    if name in unique_apps:
        duplicate_apps.append(name)
    else:
        unique_apps.append(name)
```

Your variable `app` will iterate over the column names. But if you want to iterate over a column named `name` you would have to do it like this:

```
for idx, row in android.iterrows():
    name = row['name']
    if name in unique_apps:
        duplicate_apps.append(name)
    else:
        unique_apps.append(name)
```

But this isn't the best wayto do this in your example, you could instead do:

```
# create counts
counts= android.groupby(['name']).apply(len).reset_index()
counts.columns= ['name', 'count']

# get the duplicate names
counts.loc[counts['count']>1, 'name']

# get the unique names
counts.loc[counts['count']==1, 'name']
```

Note, this isn't exactly equivalent to your result, because in your result the duplicate names are a subset of the unique names. If you really want to have that, you just need to replace the last line by

```
counts.loc[:, 'name']
```

Examples:

```
android= pd.DataFrame(dict(name=['skype', 'notepad', 'messenger', 'notepad', 'play']))

# duplicates:
Out[522]: 
1    notepad
Name: name, dtype: object

# real unique values:
Out[523]: 
0    messenger
2         play
3        skype
Name: name, dtype: object
```

And if you want to work with python lists, just add `.to_list()` like in:

```
counts.loc[counts['count']==1, 'name'].to_list()
```